# MYSQL QUERY OUTPUT wit group_concat

Tags: mysql

I've a database table. like below:

```
   Search_term url                             Search_terms
___________________________________________________________________
    Best        http://localhost/klog/?p=9711   Best
    Sunscreen   http://localhost/klog/?p=9711   Sunscreen
    Best        http://localhost/klog/?p=9711   Best
    Skin        http://localhost/klog/?p=9711   Skin
    best        http://localhost/klog/?p=9722   best
    best        http://localhost/klog/?p=9722   best
```

I used this query for :

```
SELECT id,search_term,url,GROUP_CONCAT(search_term) AS search_terms FROM klog.update_to_db_search_terms WHERE url IN (SELECT distinct(url) FROM klog.update_to_db_search_terms) GROUP BY url,id
```

For this output:

```
   Search_term url                             Search_terms
___________________________________________________________________
    Best        http://localhost/klog/?p=9711   Best,sunscreen,skin 
    best        http://localhost/klog/?p=9722   best
```

But its not working.

Comment: You want to repeat `Best` term in the first case but not in the second. Why is it so?

Comment: some of the rows in the sample data are duplicated , I don't think that's right

Comment: In any case, without a PRIMARY KEY, problems of this nature are tediously complicated